# Generate MS Access Report with Opening and Closing Balance

Tags: ms-access

I have designed MS Access Table in which I have added Column name as "Closing Balance". I want to generate query so that it shows me opening balance and closing balance with respect of date as today's closing will be next day opening. the Formula of closing balance is "Total Amount Received - Total Amount Sent".  The structure of the Table is as under. [image]

I am using the following query but it does not show me any result. It shows me the blank query result. Here is the query.

```
SELECT (Select TOP 1 Closing_Balance From MainDB as Dup Where Dup.MainDB_Date <MainDB.MainD_Date);
```

Please anyone can help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: Anyone can make an exact quarry because I tried but failed.

Comment: Each day's transactions (received and sent) is not a cumulative calculation which what you need for a closing value. That would require a running sum calculation which is difficult in Access query.Review https://theaccessbuddy.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/using-ms-access-to-create-a-running-total-or-a-cumulative-sum-part-1-of-2/. Also review other query examples in Allen Browne link such as the Year-to-Date one. However, simpler in Access report because textbox has RunningSum property. You should explore that approach.

Comment: DSum is calculating the totals. But I need clsoeing_Balance as Opening Balance for each day. Then I will add-up Opening_Balance + Total_Amount_Received - Total_Amount_Sent. This will be Closing_Balance.

Comment: I need previous day balance as an opening balance using Querry. I tried the above query it works but give the same result of top row 1. Anyone can guide please. thanks